# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined with node.js extend class

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, oop, model-view-controller

router.ts

```
import UserController from './controllers/UserController'
router.get( '/users', UserController.getAll);
```

Controller.ts

```
 class Controller {
    
     async _getAll() { 
         return {user: "test"}
     }
    
 }

export default Controller
```

UserController.ts

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express"
import Controller from "./Controller";


class UserController extends Controller {
  
    async getAll (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const response = await this._getAll() 
        return res.status( 200 ).json( response )
    }

}

export default new UserController( );
```

My main question is i want to use get function other controllers extends from Controller.ts but getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_getAll') at
> /private/var/www/project/src/controllers/UserController.ts:8:37

Comment: `router.get( '/users', UserController.getAll);` -> `router.get( '/users', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => UserController.getAll(req, res, next));` or `router.get( '/users', UserController.getAll.bind(UserController));` or you can directly bind the method when attaching it to the instance.

Comment: by the way i tried to use auto-bind package but it's occur this error:

Comment: /private/var/www/project/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:851 return old(m, filename);

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module node_modules/auto-bind/index.js  not supported.